# Three.js - add text to plane using decal

Tags: three.js

Following https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry,
I am trying to 'place' text on a simple 20X20 plane positioned at (0,10,0), as below. However, the decal is being rendered below the plane:

[image: decal below plane]

Am I oversimplifying this?

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x4a5f70, opacity: 0.8, transparent: true});
var face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
face.position.setX(0);
face.position.setY(0);
face.position.setZ(10);

var decalGeometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(
    face, 
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,10),
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), //z axis
    new THREE.Vector3(20,20,20), 
    new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)
);

var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xAAAAAA,
  map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/images/top.png'),
  side: THREE.FrontSide,
  opacity: 1.0,
  transparent: true,
  depthTest: true,
  depthWrite: false,
  polygonOffset: true,
  polygonOffsetFactor: -4,
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( decalGeometry, decalMaterial );

this.scene.add(face);
this.scene.add(mesh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is actually working as intended, the decal mesh does not overlap the original one but makes a new one. I actually tried changing the plane to a sphere and the "top.png" texture gets projected accordingly.

The parameters in `decalGeometry` define the position of the projection mesh, but not the resulting mesh (which is positioned on (0,0,0)). The end result is that you end up rendering two meshes: the original one displaced and the resulting one (with the decal projection) centered at (0,0,0).

[image]

The following code does not work if the "top.png" image is not found, but you can try it out locally.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;
var grid;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  // Scene Setup
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth*0.993, window.innerHeight*0.993 );
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 110 );
  camera.position.set( 50, 50, 0 );

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xcccccc);
  //Cube
 geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1e-3, 1e-3, 1e-3 );
 material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
 cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 scene.add( cube );

  //Camera Pivot
  camera.lookAt( cube.position );
  cube.add( camera );

  // Grid
  grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 100, 10 ) 
  scene.add(grid);

  // Geometry
  //var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50);
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(10,32,32)
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x4a5f70, opacity: 0.8, transparent: true, side:THREE.DoubleSide});
  var face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  face.position.setX(0);
  face.position.setY(0);
  face.position.setZ(30);

  var decalGeometry = new THREE.DecalGeometry(
      face, 
      new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0),
      new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), //z axis
      new THREE.Vector3(20,20,20), 
      new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)
  );

  var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xAAAAAA,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('top.png'),
    side: THREE.FrontSide,
    opacity: 1.0,
    transparent: true,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: -4,
  });

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( decalGeometry, decalMaterial );

  this.scene.add(face);
  this.scene.add(mesh); 
}


function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );

  var Y_AXIS = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
  cube.rotateOnAxis( Y_AXIS, 0.005 );    // radians

 renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://combinatronics.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry/master/src/THREE.DecalGeometry.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sweet. I found that adding the decal mesh to the face mesh solved the problem that you point out. Thank you so very much!